# Posting value to web api method from ajax call why going null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-views

I am posting some values to web API method when I debug it's showing null values.

Below is a snipet code of ajax call, here I am passing `dept_name` but it's showing null in web API method.

```
var _customer = {};
            _customer.DepartmntName = txtName.val();
            _customer.DateCreated = null;
            _customer.DateModified = null;
            _customer.IsDeleted = null;
            _customer.ParentID = null;
            _customer.Icon = null;
            _customer.Paren = null;
            alert( _customer.DepartmntName);
            alert(_customer);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/AddDepSpc/InsertCustomer2",
                 data: JSON.stringify(_customer),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                alert("success" + r);
               var row = $("#tblCustomers tr:last-child").clone(true);
                    //AppendRow(row, r.CustomerId, r.Name, r.Country);
      AppendRow(row,r.dept_name.r.date_created,r.date_modified,r.IsDeleted,
       r.ParentID.r.Icon,r.Paren);
                    txtName.val("");

                }
            });
```

Below snippet code for web api method.

```
public class AddDepSpcController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/AddDepSpc/InsertCustomer2")]
        [HttpPost]
        public   master_department InsertCustomer2(master_department _customer)
        {           
            using (HRMEntities entities = new HRMEntities())
            {
                entities.master_department.Add(_customer);
                entities.SaveChanges();
                entities.SaveChanges();
            }
            return _customer;
        }      
    }
```

Now in debug mode it shows null supposed I have passed HR as department name and all the rest of parameter are null now.Expecting HR parameter value in web api method.

[image: Debug]

Comment: Where did the `id` value of `12` come from?

Comment: And your model does not even contain a property named `DepartmntName` (although there is one named `dept_name`). In fact, the only name/value pair that your posting has any relationship at all to your model is `Icon`

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's identity column.

Comment: @StephenMuecke there is no relationship in table other values are allowed null so that i am not posting in ajax call and my dept_name is inserting as null in table

Comment: Of course it is - you not sending a name/value pair for a property named `dept_name`. Use `_customer.dept_name = txtName.val();` if you wanting to bind the value of `txtName` to the `dept_name` property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right now it's working, I was posting with the wrong parameter name.Could you add your answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posting back an object that contains property names that do not match your model.

You model contains a property named `dept_name`, but the javascript object contains one named `DepartmntName`. Similarly, none of the other names match (except `Icon`). Assuming you want to bind the value of `txtName` to the models `dept_name` property, then in the script, use

```
var _customer = {};
_customer.dept_name = txtName.val(); // not DepartmntName
....
```

Note also that there is no reason to add the `null` values to the `_customer` object (they will be `null` by default in the controller). You can also delete the `contentType: "application/json",` option and just use `data: _customer,` in the ajax call instead of stringifying it.